# Auger electron spectroscopy

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, spectroscopy

I am doing Auger electron spectroscopy on a sample. I found the differential spectra is not symmetrical. For example, oxygen peak in as received sample looks symmetrical but that for carbon is not looking symmetrical. My question is why so?

[ [image]

Comment: Why do you expect Auger signals to be symmetric (or anti-symmetric)? At some level this sounds like you want to know how AES works, which is a pretty lengthy discussion not well suited to SE.

Comment: Dear Jon, Thank you for your answer. I know how AES  works. My question is why some element has a spectrum that looks pretty symmetric (both upper and the lower part has the same amplitude ) but some others are not. I am not expecting it to be symmetrical or asymmetrical, I'm just asking what I am seeing.